# Issue on Positioning Relative Box in Bootstrap Well

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/DTcHh/15456/) and let me know why I am not able to position a set of relativ and absolute positioned boxes in the bootstrap `.well`

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box-1">
      <img src="http://1u88jj3r4db2x4txp44yqfj1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/mobile-apps.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div id="box-2">This is Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#box-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and where do you want the box-2 be positioned. Right now is where suppose to be: top: 0px;
  right: 0px;

Comment: You need to remove the `position: absolute` from `#box-1` or the .well` will not have height. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to center `#box-2` inside the `.well`, which is a wrapper around the image (a fancy border, right?). Here's how you can achieve that:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#box-1 {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  /* This is for styling, so you can see it */
  max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
  min-width: 65%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box-1">
      <img src="http://1u88jj3r4db2x4txp44yqfj1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/mobile-apps.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div id="box-2"><h2>This is a Test.</h2><p>Tousled post-ironic tofu cronut, heirloom disrupt proident labore. Four dollar toast flexitarian food truck kale chips mumblecore. Consectetur shabby chic ea, ullamco aliqua small batch kogi sriracha laborum intelligentsia brooklyn. Cliche listicle exercitation sriracha whatever organic. Nesciunt minim wayfarers, squid keffiyeh fixie cupidatat raw denim. Food truck ramps deserunt in listicle, ugh etsy ut pug street art ethical hashtag godard. Pour-over placeat seitan DIY cronut mumblecore.</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to set a height (or min-height) on wrapper which you've forgot. Also you need to set overflow: hidden to #box-1 which will make your image not overflow out of the box. Actually, a container (with position:relative) doesn't adjust itself according it's absolute-positioned children. Instead your absolute-positioned children have to be set dimensions which may be relative(% units) or not-relative(fixed units like px em etc). Here you are setting both the child boxes to cover whole the container's size through top/right/bottom/left properties but your container has no implicit(generated by content) or explicit(generated by properties like width,height,padding etc)
The working code looks like this-

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    padding: .2em;
    min-height: 10em;
}
#box-1{
    position:absolute;
      left:0px;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#box-2{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did on the demo mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: So, [this is](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/DTcHh/15457/embedded/result/) what you are suggesting, right?

Comment: yes, if the questioner wants both the boxes to be absolutely positioned or he/she can keep the box containing the image in normal flow so that wrapper expands as the image does. Your solution works best for that.